# Text Decoding Problem

Tags: c#, text-decoding

So given this input string:

```
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?TEST=2C_This_Is_A_Test_of_Some_Encoding=AE?=
```

And this function:

```
private string DecodeSubject(string input)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inputText.Text, @"=\?(?<encoding>[\S]+)\?.\?(?<data>[\S]+[=]*)\?=");
            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                string encoding = m.Groups["encoding"].Value;
                string data = m.Groups["data"].Value;

                Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding.ToLower());
                if (enc == Encoding.UTF8)
                {
                    byte[] d = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                    sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(d));
                }
                else
                {                    
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);
                    string decoded = enc.GetString(bytes);
                    sb.Append(decoded);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();

        }
```

The result is the same as the data extracted from the input string. What am i doing wrong that this text is not getting decoded properly?

UPDATE

So i have this code for decoding quote-printable:

```
public string DecodeQuotedPrintable(string encoded)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
            return Regex.Replace(encoded, "=(\r\n?|\n)|=([A-F0-9]{2})", delegate(Match m)
            {
                if (byte.TryParse(m.Groups[2].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out buffer[0]))
                {
                    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            });
        }
```

And that just leaves the underscores. Do i manually convert those to spaces (Replace("_"," ")), or is there something else i need to do to handle that?

Comment: Could you clarify the problem? What do you mean, "The result is the same as the data extracted from the input string"? That sounds to me like it's working just fine.

Comment: The data gets returned still encoded.

Comment: That quoted printable decoder is fundamentally wrong. It won't be able to handle anything except 7-bit ASCII which just won't cut it for pretty much any use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you don't fully understand format of input line. Check it here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt
format is:  `encoded-word = "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="`

so you have to

1. Extranct charset(encoding in terms of .net). Not just UTF8 or Default (Utf16)
2. Extract encoding: either B for base64 Q for quoted-printable (your case!)
3. Then perform decoding to bytes then to string

Comment: converting to string should be last operation. first you should convert your text: normal symbols are casted directly to bytes, =XY are cast to byte XY.

Answer (score 2):

1. The function's not even trying to decode the [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoded stuff (the hex codes and underscores). You need to add that.
2. It's handling the encoding wrong (UTF-8 gets decoded with `Encoding.ASCII` for some bizarre reason)